# Resolution dependent backgrounds in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-8, resolution

I am following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) MSDN article to create resolution dependent backgrounds in Windows Phone 8, but it's showing blank background always.

Any one has idea what's wrong with it? Anybody has any alternative solutions?

Comment: But it's a higher resolution black on the newer models.

Comment: I'm not getting what you are saying.

Comment: And I'm not getting what you've tried, what actually happens vs what you expected, etc.

Comment: The image is not displayed, in design time I can see image in emulator it displays white or black according to theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN article has mistake in `MultiResImageChooser` class, `MultiResImageChooser` is written as `MultiResImageChooserUri` & relative URIs are missing leading slash. Correct class is given below.

```
public class MultiResImageChooser
{
    public Uri BestResolutionImage
    {
        get
        {
            switch (ResolutionHelper.CurrentResolution)
            {
                case Resolutions.HD:
                    return new Uri("/Assets/MyImage.screen-720p.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
                case Resolutions.WXGA:
                    return new Uri("/Assets/MyImage.screen-wxga.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
                case Resolutions.WVGA:
                    return new Uri("/Assets/MyImage.screen-wvga.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown resolution type");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   public enum Resolutions { WVGA, WXGA, HD720p, HD };

    private static bool IsWvga
    {
        get
        {
            return App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 100;
        }
    }

    private static bool IsWxga
    {
        get
        {
            return App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 160;
        }
    }

    private static bool Is720p
    {
        get
        {
            return App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 150;
        }
    }
    private static bool IsHD
    {
       get 
      { 
         return App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 150; 
      }
    }
```

Add this to the top of your class and use these static variables to set resolution specific images. You said you want to set "resolution dependent backgrounds", from which I understand you want to set some image on the background? If you want the image to the background of the page then set `ImageBrush` of your `LayoutRoot` Grid to resolution specific images ( 480x800.jpg, 720x1280.jpg etc) like this

```
        ImageBrush image = new ImageBrush();
        if (IsWvga)
        {
            //set your bitmap
        }
        else if (IsWxga)
        {
            //set your bitmap
        }
        else if (Is720p)
        {
            //set your bitmap
        }
        else if(IsHD)
        {
           //set your bitmap
        }
        image.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;

        LayoutRoot.Background = image;
```

OR

if you want your screen UI elements to fit in the resolutions then set the `height` of your UI elements to `auto` in XAML, or set the resolution specific height of your UI elements on the `OnNavigatedTo` event of your page. This may be any random grid of your page which needs to fit in

```
        if (IsWvga)
        {
            grid.Height = 500;
        }
        else if (IsWxga)
        {
            grid.Height = 600;
        }
        else if (Is720p)
        {
            grid.Height = 700;
        }
        else if (IsHD)
        {
            grid.Height = 800;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I don't want to go in this manner. I want to follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) approach, it's more XAML specific